# Delete notification notification.builder on content click

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification that have 2 actions. One intent open an Activity, the other open browser web.

my code:

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationClickActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    PendingIntent pBrowserIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, browserIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(shortDescription)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(longDescription))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_defaulticon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent1)
            .addAction(R.drawable.playstore_icon_32, "Dettagli", pIntent1)
            .setContentIntent(pBrowserIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.small_defaulticon, "Vai al sito", pBrowserIntent).build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
      (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

If i click on the notification it goes away, but if I click on one of the 2 Actions it open the right intent but notification doesn't cleared.
I try also `.setDeleteIntent(myPendingIntent)` but nothing... I wonder where I am going wrong...

A screen of my notification...

[image: notification]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A notification is never dismissed when an action button is pressed. It just sends you associated intent. If you want it to dismiss, you need to call [`NoficationManager.cancel(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29) to cancel it yourself. You will normally do it in the same method, which handles action button intent.

`Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` flag you tried to use is only applied to notification body and not to action buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not understand where I should put `NotificationManager.cancel(int id)`. My first action buttons starts an activity, should I put in `onCreate` of that activity? But the second action starts an browser intent..

Comment: For the first action, you can put this code into `onCreate()` of that activity. For the second action, you could do it as following. You need to start your activity first, then call `cancel()`, launch browser intent, and immediately `finish()` your activity. All this you need to do in `onCreate()` method. This would be a proxy activity with no layout then.

Comment: I tried. In the first case all is ok :) But with the second action no: I created a "BrowserActivity" and in the `onCreate` of this class I delete the notification and I start the browser intent with `startActivity(browserIntent)` but the `BrowserActivity` is never called.. I don't know why..

Comment: Can you publish code of how you browser intent? Don't forget to call `finish()` after browser is started too.

Comment: DONE! damn manifest! Since I work on a notification library project I forgot to add `BrowserActivity` in the main project manifest.xml! Thank you for support, right answer & +1.

Answer (score 1):

use cancel() in the activity that started by your action to dismiss the notification

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

and try to send uniqueId in `notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, noti);`

Comment: thanks for your answer, "uniqueId" is an unique id for the 2 action buttons or an unique number for the notification? `NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)` replace my `Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)`?

Comment: uniqueId is an unique number for notification. Yes replace it Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context) is depreciated now.